# Django wagtail accesing parent page variables from block templates

Tags: django, jinja2, wagtail

I have created a stream block with a custom template in my models.py file for my 'work' page as:

```
section = StreamBlock( [ ('section', SectionStreamBlock( template = 'personal_web/blocks/work_block.html') ])
```

I am listing my 'work page' objects in a 'work-index page'. As  `work-index page  > work page > block`

Now I am trying to access the 'work page object' itself  in my block template. (I am using jinja2 )

I know that I can not pass it via {% include_block block %}.

Is there a way to pass it?

Answer (score 0):

The [`{% include_block %}`](http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v1.13/advanced_topics/jinja2.html#include-block) tag works in the similar way to the [`{% include %}`](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.9/templates/#include)tag from Jinja2 in terms of passing context to a child template. So if you render the `section` streamfield in your page template like this:

```
{% include_block page.section %}
```

In your `personal_web/blocks/work_block.html` you should be able to access your "work" page object using the `page` variable (for example, `page.title` to access page's title).

Comment: But  I am listing 'work page objects' on the page 'works-index page' so when I do {{ page.title }} in blocks I get the  'works-index page' title?

Comment: Ah, it wasn't clear for the original question - thanks for the update. This happens because in you case `page` is `works-index page` (because you render `work page`'s blocks on a `works-index page`, not on a `work page`). This means that to access `work page` you need to refer a page in a block template as they appear in `works-index page`'s template. I guess, you have a something like `{% for work_page in works_index_page_child_pages %}`, so you need `{{ work_page.title }}` to get a title.

If it doesn't work for you, please, add your models and templates into the question.